# Unable to browse Image folders through Whatsapp

Tags: iphone, ios

On opening whatsapp, if I want to send any photos via option 'Choose Existing Photo' to any of my contacts, the only thing I can browse is 'Camera Roll' and 'Favorites'. Apart from these two I have many folders in my iphone.

Can someone help me how can I let whatsapp see the rest of the folders? Is there any setting I need to change?

Any help much appreciated. It's becoming very painful to share photos and the only method right now is via copy and paste individually.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, is it still happening? What version of Whatsapp are you using? The names of the action you mention don't match mine.

Comment: It's fixed now with the whatsapp update. Whenever I need to add a photo, it takes me to Photo Library but during the time I queried it was a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

I am no longer receiving this error and it seems to have fixed with the whatsapp update.